# MySQL: Check if row exists does not really work

Tags: php, mysql

I have encountered a genuine problem which cause is uknown to me.
I am inserting datetime into database (and some other data). Script works, it is adding new records and it's just swell. The genuine problem is about duplicating data. Even though I have this if-condition, it does not work properly :x

```
$data = $year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$godzina.":".$minuta;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from kolejka WHERE data LIKE '$data%'");
$exists = (mysql_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
if($exists){
    header('Location: location');
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'text';
}else{
 $sql = "INSERT INTO kolejka (pID, mID, data, odbyta) VALUES ('$id', '$mid', '$data', '0')";
}
if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    header('Location: 'location');
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'error';
}
```

here's db:

[image: db]

It's got to be done by mysql_query :> 
Thanks in advance for any comments

Comment: Echo out `$data`, what do you get?

Comment: Did you maybe trim your code for the example too much? _I don't see where the insert is executed._

Comment: @aynber 2016-08-09 9:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that by concatenating the values like that, you're not padding the numbers, so they don't match. ( 9:00 != 09:00) You want to create a valid date format from your variables with [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
 $data = date('Y-m-d H:i', mktime ($godzina, $minuta, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

Comment: I did it other way around, but you inspired me what's the cause. Thank you buddy